# Reflect object from exact centre using reflect tool - Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, reflection

Is there a way to reset, or position the cyan anchor(not sure what its called) in the exactly in the middle of an object when using the reflect tool? I know if I click on what I assume to be the centre it will reflect from there but was wondering if theres a more accurate way to do it? Its not defaulting to the centre when I click back into the tool as you can see in screenshot it's off centre.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Double-click** the **Reflect Tool** in the toolbar.

This will *automatically* use the center of the selection as the origin point for the reflection.

Or, choose `Object > Transform > Reflect...`,
...same thing basically. Double-clicking is just easier `:)`.

---

The double-click works to bring up the dialog window for all the tools associated with the transform operations in the Object Menu, such as Rotate, Reflect, Move, Sheer, etc. And by default, they will always use the center of the current selection for the origin point.